# Indirect reference to sheet names

Tags: excel

I have a several worksheets named `Order 1`, `Order 2` etc. and a main sheet with the following table:

```
   A               B     
1 Buying           Price 
2 Order 1      ='Order 1'!P2 
3 Order 2      ='Order 2'!P2
```

ColumnA has the name of the relevant worksheet and ColumnB returns the value of `P2` in that worksheet.

How do I modify the formula `='Order 1'!P2` so that the text is taken from the corresponding cell in ColumnA?

Tried a lot but every time I am getting incorrect formula error.

Comment: so you want the text of A1 followed by the value of P2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the INDIRECT formula:

```
=INDIRECT("'"&A2&"'"&"!$P$2")
```

A2 is the reference to the sheet name

Comment: May need single quotes as the worksheet name in A2 seems to have a space. e.g. `=INDIRECT("'"&A2&"'!P2")` ([INDIRECT Function](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/indirect-function-HP010062413.aspx))

Comment: @Jeeped: Yes you are right. I changed my post. I hope it is correct now. :-)